# I cant run my react program because components are not included.,advice?

Tags: node.js

Ive been trying stuff for hours like instructions from the message, videos and forums on how to tackle this issue. It started because i kept missing modules like fs, http and https. I tried npm I to these missing files but to no aveil, the error message persisted.
url to repo:
https://github.com/JonathanDaboush/employeeportal.git
I get this message

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-loader": "8.1.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal\node_modules\babel-loader (version: 9.1.2)  

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.       
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-loader" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal\node_modules\babel-loader is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-loader in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-loader.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.        

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

PS C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal> npm start

> divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-loader": "8.1.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal\node_modules\babel-loader (version: 9.1.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.     
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-loader" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal\node_modules\babel-loader is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-loader in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-loader.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.        

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete this file below and replace it with some different version(s) if possible?

C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\divinapopinam2frontendemployeeportal\node_modules\babel-loader (version: 9.1.2)

Are you sure that you don't need "babel-loader": "8.1.0" instead of 9.1.2?

Maybe start from scratch in a new environment, with and without different versions of babel-loader?

Or try to research common incompatibility issues encountered by others using babel-loader? Maybe it is because you are trying to use it with something else that junks up something that babel-loader needs on the backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. It will permanently disable this preflight check.